# Error when using pypdftk - returned non-zero exit status 127

Tags: python, pdftk

I am on Mac OS and have `pip install pypdftk` and have downloaded pdftk from the official website.

When I run commands for pypdftk like:

`import pypdftk
pypdftk.fill_form('testing.pdf', out_file='flattened.pdf', flatten=True)`

I get this error

`CalledProcessError: Command '/usr/bin/pdftk testing.pdf fill_form /var/folders/h4/----/T/---- output flattened.pdf flatten' returned non-zero exit status 127`

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you still need this answered, but I came across this same error today. For me, the cause was not having pdftk installed on my machine. It looks like this library requires the server version found here: https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-server/

Also, the default path is `/usr/bin/pdftk`, so you may have to add the `PDFTK_PATH` environment variable to make it work.